# Задача на динамическое программирование: монотонный рост суммы

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Даны 2 массива. Длина второго не меньше длины первого. Нужно подобрать последовательность индексов `s[i]` 2 массива, так чтобы они

1. шли в возрастающем порядке (`s[i] < s[i+1]`)
2. для любого i `a[i] + b[ s[i] ] < a[i+1] + b[ s[i + 1] ]`

В ответ нужно вывести индексы второго массива тех чисел, которые были сложены.

```
Дано:
n - длина первого массива.
m - длина второго массива.
a - первый массив.
b - второй массив.
2 <= n <= m <= 3000
прибавляем массив a к b  

Пример:

Ввод:
3 5
21 12 19
10 20 10 20 10

Вывод:
1 2 4
```

Поясняю пример:
Складываем a[1] и b[1], получается 31. Складываем a[2] и b[2], получается 32. Складываем a[3] и b[4], получается 39. Условие выполнено, последовательность возрастает `a[1] + b[1] < a[2] + b[2] < a[3] + b[4]`, ответ(индексы массива b): 1 2 4.

Comment: не знаю к чему люди минусы ставят, задача не является тривиальной. К примеру, не работают жадные алгоритмы, которые используют минимальное возможное `s[i]` либо такое `s[i]`, которое минимально сумму `a[i] + b[ s[i] ]` увеличивает. [Пример кода на Питоне](https://gist.github.com/zed/edeb03976aeb4b7c8f952ec7d9f96e3f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача явно олимпиадная. Это динамика.

Основание динамики - то, что мы можем сочетать элемент `a[0]` с любым из `b` и получать сумму `a[0] + b[k]`. В чём идея динамики. Если мы взяли первые `i` элементов из массива `a`, и `a[i] --> b[j]` то нам уже не важно, какие индексы были для всех меньших `i`. Таким образом, динамика показываем *минимальную* сумму `a[i] + b[j]` если эта сумма получается какой-либо последовательностью индексов, не противоречащей условию. Можно хранить только 1 слой динамики (т.к. следующий вычисляется из предыдущего). В решении это массив `F`.

Пересчёт. Чтобы мы могли взять пару `(i,j)` достаточно (и необходимо). Чтобы существовала пара `(i-1,k), k < j` такая что `F[k] < a[i] + b[j]`. Можно заметить, что `min(F[k], k < j)` можно просчитать сразу после получения всего массива `F`, что мы и сделаем в массив `minF`.

Восстановление ответа. Заведём массивы `posMinF`  который будет показывать где именно в массиве `F` был минимальный элемент среди первых `k` элементов. И массив `toRepairAnswer` который будем использовать для сохранения переходов (это самое критичное место по памяти, возможно есть смысл сделать его разреженным, но не для этих условий).

Сложность `O(n*m)` по памяти и времени.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int F[50];
int minF[50];
int posMinF[50];
int a[50];
int b[50];

int toRepairAnswer[50][50];

#define inf 1000000


int main(){
    int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    for (int i=0; i < N;i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (int i=0;i < M;i++)
        cin >> b[i];

    for (int i=0; i < M;i++)
        F[i] = a[0] + b[i];

    minF[0] = inf;

    for (int i = 1; i < N;i++){
        for (int k=0; k < M;k++)
            if (minF[k] < F[k]){
                minF[k+1] = minF[k];
                posMinF[k] = posMinF[k-1];
            } else {
                minF[k + 1] = F[k];
                posMinF[k] = k;
            }

        for (int k=0; k < M;k++)
            if (minF[k] < a[i] + b[k]){
                F[k] = a[i] + b[k];
                toRepairAnswer[i][k] = posMinF[k-1];
            }
            else F[k] = inf;
    }


    int res = -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
        if (F[k] < inf){
            res = k;
            break;
        }
    if (res == -1){
        cout << "No Answer";
        return 0;
    }
    for (int k = N -1; k >= 0; k--){
        cout << res+1<<" ";
        res = toRepairAnswer[k][res];
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне не понятны некоторые моменты.
1. В третьем абзацы вы, возможно, имели в виду a[0] + b[0]?
2. Не понимаю синтаксис этого выражения "F[i][j+1] = a[i] + b[j] | (min (F[i-1][k] | k <= j) < a[i][j])", | - это побитовое "И"? Какую оно тут играет роль?

Comment: ну во-первых или а не И. А во-вторых это из мат логики. "Таких что" читать надо.

Comment: Извиняюсь за ошибки, я измучился сегодня с этой задачей, поэтому могу тормозить. Можно ли ваше выражение в 4 абзаце описать как "число из первого массива плюс минимум из второго массива до j"? Я не очень понимаю, что вы прибавляете к a[i], что такое просто [j] и почему вы считаете минимум из посчитанных значений другого числа и сравниваете его с текущим значением. Если можете, объясните на примере n=2, m=5, a={10, 8}, b={3, 5, 4, 1, 2}

Comment: Возможно, вы меня неправильно поняли, я попытался написать сразу мат. модель задачи, чтобы не нагружать никому мозг лишний раз. Вот [тут](http://oi-minsk.id1945.com/2015-16/city/statements2.pdf)  условие, задача номер 2.

Comment: решение не полное (индексы `s[i]` не получены явно) и не работает, если я правильно его понял (если оно эквивалентно [`p_min_grow()` решению](https://gist.github.com/zed/edeb03976aeb4b7c8f952ec7d9f96e3f))

Comment: @jfs сейчас на С++ напишу. Сравним.

Comment: @jfs https://ideone.com/DlCVbk заранее извините за код) писал в своём стиле. Потом отрефакторю. Предполагаю что ответ существует. Если нет - 1 строку поменять.

Comment: [простые](https://ideone.com/3Bgu2Z) [тесты](https://ideone.com/Kp2Fuj) проходит. Опишите алгоритм в ответе, что величины Q, backup, backup_value представляют.

Comment: *"Опишите алгоритм в ответе"*

Comment: @jfs обновил ответ.